# Python: weird floating-point math results

Tags: python, math, while-loop, floating-point, modulo

```
number = 9.3

while number % 0.5 != 0:
    number -= 0.1

print number
```

> > > -20.0

I expected number to end up leaving this while loop as 9.0, but somehow it has become -20.0. Note that if I change number to 9.2 it works just as I would expect and becomes 9.0. Some values work such as 9.0, 9.7 and some don't such as 9.4, 9.8. I have no clue why. By the way 9.8 becomes -1204.5 which is even more weird. I can't explain these results. Forgive me if I've missed something basic as I have only just begun to learn computer programming.

Comment: [Floating point math](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is the problem.

Comment: Try using the `fractions` module instead.

Comment: Or possibly `decimal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of floating point precision. If you print `number` and `number % 0.5` in the loop, you will get something like:

```
9.2 0.2
9.1 0.1
9.0 1.7763568394e-15  # Not equal to 0!
8.9 0.4
8.8 0.3
8.7 0.2
8.6 0.1
8.5 3.5527136788e-15  # Still different from 0!
...
```

And it happens that when `number` reaches -20, the solution is exact:

```
-20.0 0.0
```

What you should do is, instead of checking equality with 0, check if the result is *small enough*:

```
EPSILON = 0.0001
number = 9.3
while number % 0.5 > EPSILON:
    number -= 0.1
print number
```

And the result will be `9.0`.

---

But if you want a *cleaner* solution which does not involve loops, this will always work:

```
import math
number = 0.5 * math.floor(2.0 * number)
```

Comment: No, you should really just avoid accumulating roundoff in the first place.

Comment: @tmyklebu I disagree: maybe the OP does something else than a simple substraction in its loop that require the temporary value. And in every case, answering with a totally different solution would not help him either to understand the problem.

Comment: Disagree all you like, but don't advocate a broken solution based on comparison against an arbitrarily-chosen epsilon.  You can give a roundoff-error analysis of repeated subtraction to justify a particular (much tighter) choice of epsilon, or you can avoid the roundoff entirely.  Also note that your method will likely break if 0.1 is replaced with a number whose floating-point representation is larger than the user's naive expectation.

Comment: @tmyklebu Edited my answer with a cleaner one-liner